# Script to open web pages, fill texts and click buttons

Tags: python, facebook, text, authentication, fill

I'd like to write a script, preferably a Python code, to fill text areas in web pages and then click certain buttons. I've come across some solutions for this but none worked, mainly because cookies were not stored properly, for exmaple, there was a Python script to login to Facebook, which did seem to get it right in the shell screen, but when I opened Facebook in the browser it was logged out like nothing happened. Also, the code was hard coded for Facebook and I'm asking for something more general. So, please, if anyone had been successful with these kind of things, your advice is much needed. Open a web page, fill text in specified text elements, click a specified button, save cookies, that's all. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) will do everything you want.

Systems like mechanize are essentially self-contained.  They maintain their own cookie-store, so those cookies don't end up in the browser - the same way that cookies from one browser (e.g. Firefox) don't show up in another one (e.g. Chrome).

Comment: Looks like just what I needed, thank you so much for the link and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take a look at [IEC](http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/index.php) which uses windows API to run an instance of Internet explorer and give commands to it. Although it may not be good for large scale automation,
but it is very easy to use.

Answer (score -2):

You can also take a look at IEC which uses windows API to run an instance of Internet explorer and give commands to it. Although it may not be good for large scale automation, but it is very easy to use.